# Linux command line

Tags: linux, command

I wish  pass the command from a tutorial

[How I check the command that is pretend?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKOEC.png)

chmod maybe result but I don't have permissions, I don't know how can I do...

P.S I probably forget the point .

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `nano ~/.bash_profile` to get you .bash_profile file in the nano text editor.